# Why is the output 0 when using equality inside printf?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int var = 10 ; 
    printf ( "\n%d %d",var==10, var = 100) ;
}
```

Output:

```
0 100
```

Inside the printf statement, `var==10` evaluates to true but then I'm getting the output as `0`. Why does this happen?

Comment: See: [Why are these constructs (using ++) undefined behavior?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-using-undefined-behavior)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're modifying `var` inside of the function call.  Parameters to a function can be evaluated in any order.  In this particular example, `var = 100` is being evaluated before `var==10`, but there's no guarantee the behavior will be the same if you use a different compiler.

Because you're attempting to read and modify a variable in the same expression without a sequence point to separate them, you're invoking [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).